# Does "Taken up" imply an Agent's involvement? Angel? or God?

Tags: jesus, resurrection, heaven

**Taken Up** Several times in the New Testament the phrase ***taken up*** (although one word in the Greek) is used to refer to one's death, and especially of Jesus's Ascension (since He was no longer dead, His "taking up" was unique).

But does not ***taken up*** imply that someone is dong the "taking"? Could it be an angel? or God Himself? Or is this wording merely figurative? Does the Bible itself interpret this for us?

> ***analepseos*** (Gk.) And it came to pass, when the time was come that He should be taken up, He steadfastly set His face to go to Jerusalem. (Luke 9:51)

> ***analambano*** (Gk.) Jesus began to do and teach until the day in which He was taken up... (Acts 1:1-2) This same Jesus Who is taken up from you into heaven, shall so come in like manner...(Acts 1:11) Beginning from the baptism of John, unto the same day that He was taken up from us... (Acts 1:22; see also Mark 16:19, 1 Timothy 3:16)

> ***eperthe*** (Gk.) While they beheld, He was taken up, and a cloud withdrew Him out of their sight. (Acts 1:9)

Each of these Greek words are faithfully translated according to Koine Greek as a "taking up" or "taking again" but also translated as "receiving back" by some. (**Thayer's Greek Lexicon**)

There is a similar word in Matthew 24:40,41, ***paralambano** (Gk.), that is used to describe the *taking out* of "one in the field" at the Second Coming of Christ. The root is the same as the Greek word in Acts 1 (where it is repeated three times.). Jesus is taking out the people (?).

If, when it comes to leaving this world (either resurrected from the dead, or ascending while alive) should not another word have been used such as "leave" or "vacate" instead of "being "taken up", unless there was to be an emphasis on an ***agent*** being involved in the process?

[Does the departure of Elijah shed some light on this "being taken". (2 Kings 2:9-18)]

Answer (score 1):

The usage of these words are often amplified when referencing them in the LXX. While *analempseos* is not found in the LXX, *analambano* is used numerous times such as in Daniel 4:34 ESV, "At the end of the days I, Nebuchadnezzar, **lifted** my eyes to heaven . . ." In this case, the lifting is volitional but figurative (i.e. no floating eyeballs in space).

*Epairó* is also used numerous times in the LXX such as in Genesis 7:17, "The flood continued forty days on the earth. The waters increased and **bore up** the ark, and it rose high above the earth." So, in this case, the agent doing the lifting was the flood water.

An excellent source for Greek usage is the scholarly reference, *A Greek-English Lexicon of the New Testament and Other Early Christian Literature* (aka the BDAG). On p.67, column 1, we see that *analempseos* is used only in Luke 9:51 to mean ascension (into heaven), but in extra-biblical writings, it can also mean death or decease in presumably post New Testament writings.

Answer (score 1):

**Yes it does**. The Bible clearly says that Jesus will send his angels and they shall collect the saints from all over the world

**Mathew 24:31**

> And he will send out his angels with a loud trumpet call, and they will gather his elect from the four winds, from one end of heaven to the other.

The Bible is clear about the rapture and two people will be watching news together, one will be taken by an angel and the other one will be left.

Comment: @ Dong Li - Thanks for your response. However, when referencing the Bible (i.e. "the Bible is clear...") it is best ***not to add*** ideas or wording that is not there. "Angel" is not mentioned in Matthew 24:40-41.  Also, check to see if verse 31 refers to the same event as verses 40-41. Keep studying the Bible; it will draw you closer to Jesus!

Comment: @raygrant, am talking about Mathew 24:31, your talking about Mathew 24:40